# Get data from MongoDB for dc.js charts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dc.js

How to modify following index.html and dc.js code to pull [data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dc-js/dc.js/master/web/examples/morley.csv) from MongoDB database using Node.js rather than csv?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/1.7.5/dc.css"/> 
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <h3>
     <div class="dc-data-count">
      <span class="filter-count"></span> selected out of <span class="total-count"></span> transitions | <a href="javascript:dc.filterAll(); dc.renderAll();">Reset All</a>
     </div>
    </h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div id="pie-chart"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div id="bar-chart"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.9/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.8/d3.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.0.0-beta.29/dc.js"></script> 

  <script type="text/javascript">

   d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dc-js/dc.js/master/web/examples/morley.csv", function (err, experiments) {

    if (err) throw err;

    var pieChart = dc.pieChart("#pie-chart");
    var barChart = dc.barChart("#bar-chart");
    var visCount = dc.dataCount(".dc-data-count");

    experiments.forEach(function(x) {
     x.Speed = +x.Speed;
    });

    var ndx = crossfilter(experiments);
    var all = ndx.groupAll();

    runDimension_pie = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return "run-"+d.Run;})
    speedSumGroup_pie = runDimension_pie.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.Speed * d.Run;});
    runDimension_bar = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Run;}),
    speedSumGroup_bar = runDimension_bar.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.Speed * d.Run / 1000;});

     visCount
     .dimension(ndx)
     .group(all);

    pieChart
     .width(768)
     .height(480)
     .slicesCap(4)
     .innerRadius(100)
     .dimension(runDimension_pie)
     .group(speedSumGroup_pie)
     .legend(dc.legend())
        .on('pretransition', function(chart) {
            chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function(d) {
                return d.data.key + ' ' + dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2*Math.PI) * 100) + '%';
            })
        });

    barChart
     .width(768)
        .height(480)
        .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([6,20]))
        .brushOn(false)
        .yAxisLabel("This is the Y Axis!")
        .dimension(runDimension_bar)
        .group(speedSumGroup_bar)
        .on('renderlet', function(chart) {
            chart.selectAll('rect').on("click", function(d) {
                console.log("click!", d);
            });
     });;

    dc.renderAll();

   })

  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

I tried creating and using the following index.js. I get JSON at http://localhost:3000/api/data but I'm not sure how to set Node up properly to pass data to current index.html and update charts accordingly.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connection_URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
const connection_DB = "myDatabase";

mongoose.connect(connection_URI, {dbName: connection_DB});

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var connection = mongoose.connection;

var Runs = mongoose.model('Run', new Schema({
}), 'morley');

app.get('/api/data', function(req, res) {
 Runs.find({}, {}, function(err, runDetails) {
  if (err) 
  res.send(err);
  res.json(runDetails);
 });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```

I looked at [this example](https://anmolkoul.wordpress.com/2015/06/05/interactive-data-visualization-using-d3-js-dc-js-nodejs-and-mongodb/) as a reference, but it's a bit too complicated.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question - once you have the JSON response, you should be able to initialize your crossfilter with that, as long as it is an array of some sort?

Comment: I believe that you're right: since I have the JSON API response, I should be able to initialize the crossfilter. However, since I'm new to Node, I'm having a problem writing the proper code to correctly get the response from the API to initialize the crossfilter via `d3.json()`.

Comment: I still don't understand. You won't be running Node on the client side, just D3. If you are successfully able to make the request then you don't have a Node problem. However,   you *might* have a CORS problem? If you are getting cross-origin errors on the browser console, you'll want to look into 1. serving your HTML from the same server or 2. adding the appropriate header to your response. Otherwise just plug the URL into your `d3.csv` call and that should be end of story.

Comment: Er, that is, you would use `d3.json` if it's a JSON source. Hope you figured it out!